# What would my industry-wide job title be, seeing as I don't code enough to really call myself a developer?

Tags: software-industry, title

What would my actual title be if I were to apply it industry-wide? The term used at my company (Application Analyst) don't seem to apply elsewhere.

A similar title is 'Software Architect', except I have only 1 year of experience. It's not that high up, but it's that career path. It's not a pure coding role, it's impact analysis, creating design documentation, analysing existing code through the lens of client needs, information gathering, etc. Someone like me, after enough career progression, would be responsible for like high level design choices.

It feels strange to say 'programmer'. I think I'll ultimately move away from coding quite quickly. The requirements for jobs I could look for in the future won't be about knowing specific languages or frameworks but rather more people and business oriented roles. Already now I'd say the coding is not a huge part of my job. I spend a lot more times in meetings and writing technical documents.

It's mostly a concern because I am *not* really coding that much so when it comes to future jobs, I am not working towards anything that says 'X years of experience with Y language, framework, etc.'

What title would sound the prettiest based on what I'm describing?

Comment: What title *does* your company give your role? it might be easier to "translate" if we knew what that was.

Comment: @motosubatsu I've updated my post with this information. The title is 'Application Analyst'.

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a few steps ahead of where a lot of developers go. In software development it's not uncommon to see a developer move into management positions. This seems like you'd more on the management side than the programming side. So maybe try for technical product manager type roles if possible

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what YOE stands for. You should avoid using acronyms.

Comment: "**EDIT: To clarify, the title my company gives me is 'Application Analyst.'**". Then, your job title is just that:  "**Application Analyst**". You can explain more about what you actually do at work in your resume.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would highly recommend that you learn to write in a more concise and professional manner especially when you claim your role to be one of design documentation, etc. Your post was difficult to follow at times due to sentence fragmentation, incomplete thoughts and unprofessional injections of words such as "like", "yeah", etc.

Second, there is NO WAY you can call yourself a Software Architect with 1 year of experience and little to no experience with a technical stack.

With that being said, it sounds to me like you are more of a Business Analyst than a developer. I have hired people as Business Analysts and their responsibility was to interface with the client, understand user requirements, write requirements documentation, user stories, define user personas etc. They were not responsible for coding or the technical design of a system.

Another possible title is the simple title of "Software Engineer". This can mean a great deal of things and does not have to imply someone who writes software for a living but participates in the overall design and development of software to some extent. I have worked with many testers with that title who never wrote a line of code in their life.

Good luck.

Comment: "Software Engineer [...] can mean a great deal of things and does not have to imply someone who writes software for a living" Where I'm from, "Software Engineer" *very much* implies that you write code.

Comment: @Celos Perhaps that is your experience but it isn't the case all of the time. Like I said in my comment, I have worked with testers and other members of the "software engineering process" that have held that title.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a Product Manager (not a Project Manager) to me.  Business Analyst is something very similar I think, but that term tends to be used in tech adjacent industries, not in the tech industry itself.

Comment: @GabeSechan As a former software engineering manager, I have hired Business Analysts to do requirements and it was a title that was easily accepted by our customers, etc.

Comment: @rhoonah Any title you give them will be accepted by your customers, nobody really cares.  But BA isn't really used in the tech industry.  Maybe in some of the fields aroun it that use tech heavily, like finance.  But inside the tech industry the job of interacting with customers, gathering product requirements, writing user stories, etc is called product manager.

Comment: @GabeSechan That's your experience and mine is different. I don't think you can speak for the tech industry as a whole any more than I can. Even if you were right, so what? I am sure an intelligent person in the tech industry could easily translate that title to something they are more familiar with like product manager or something else.

Comment: @rhoonah Sure, after asking what the hell a business analyst is.  Nobody in tech knows it, and their assumption is going to be sales or strategy based on the word "business", not product.

Comment: @GabeSechan I can see we're not getting anywhere since you're not capable of grasping  the concept that things can be true outside of your own life experience so we can just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone more experienced than me maybe help me figure out exactly
> what title would sound the prettiest based on what I'm describing?
>
> Just for clarity's sake I'd love to know what my actual title would be
> if I were to apply it industry-wide but it feels the terms used at my
> company don't apply elsewhere, so it's hard to know what I'd be
> called.

All titles are local. They can be determined by the corporation, and the project takes people who have the skill sets they need, regardless of the title. I have seen the titles determined by the customer. They say we want a developer, an engineer, and an architect and this is what skills they need. The company finds the right people regardless of title within the company.

Even if we come to a consensus regarding the perfect title for what you do, other companies and projects won't use the same decoder ring.

Answer (score 0):

From how you describe the job, Application Analyst sounds perfect. It's not an uncommon job title, though other companies may have variations around the 'analyst' portion. If you want to continue this kind of work in the future, look for analyst positions. I have seen people who advance in this role go on into 'product owner' and 'project management' positions.